# Animate up from bottom of screen?

Tags: html, css

My .filter-list is hidden off screen, I wish to bring this up on hover (ideally animated) using just CSS.

On hover I've got the menu appearing by changing the bottom property, the problem is, how can I get the .filter-list to animate and sit exactly above it's parent li without using JS to get it's height and changing the bottom value to that?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="small-2 columns filter-category">
        Category
        <ul class="filter-list">
            <li>element one</li>
            <li>element two</li>
            <li>element three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.filter-category{

    &:hover ul{

        bottom: 100px;
    }

}

.filter-list{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: -99999px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your CSS's .filter-list position from "absolute" to something else?

Comment: What if you used top instead of bottom to position the list off screen?  The CSS `animate: top 1s;` (or similar - there are browser-prefixes too) should take care of the animating, but you have to tell it where it should wind up (whether you can set that as a static value or need to get it with JS depends on how the page looks/works I think).

Comment: @MikeB. "but you have to tell it where it should wind up" this is my question, how can I work this out without JS?

Comment: @user1789573 could you show an example?

Comment: @dowomenfart does not answer my question - it needs to slide up and sit exactly above parent li

Comment: @panthro I don't think you'll be able to do it without JS.  If you have a separate "animating/floating" element for every li, you might be able to position it off-screen then remove that positioning to return it to its "default" place.  But I doubt that would be very efficient.

Comment: its a little hacky method but it gives the outcome http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/upmevbsj/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes not at all what im after, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way would be to set display:none for filter-list then back to display:inline-block on hover. I have adjusted positioning for it to fit appropriately, but you may want to modify it further to work with your site.

There are popular css libs that have drop-up controls such as bootstrap, try that out if you can.

```css
.filter-list {
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.filter-category {
    position:relative;
}

ul:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}

.filter-list-holder {
    list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class='filter-list-holder'>
        <ul class="filter-list">
            <li>element one</li>
            <li>element two</li>
            <li>element three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns filter-category">Category</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This CSS is in my question?!

Comment: Sorry- could you clarify what you mean by "sit exactly above the parent li"? I thought you were having trouble getting the ul to move up.

Comment: I want it to sit exactly above it, I'm not sure how many pixels above it it is. How can I work it out? The parent li is fluid too.

Comment: Oh, so you want it to sort of pop-up? Like a drop-up list? As in- you hover over category and the items appear up.

Comment: Yes, a drop up list. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but you've used an static position for bottom on .filter-list, what happens with people who have increased font sizes?

Comment: Check out the edit. I moved the ul above the li and instead of using display:none it will use visibility rule which maintains the structure dimensions.

Comment: Thanks but this is not valid html.

Comment: Wrapped the drop-up ul in an li.

Comment: Thanks, how would you animate this coming up from the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Do you mean literally the bottom or just to give the appearance of animating upwards to its final location?

Comment: Unfortunately for that, you have a conflict in requirements. With valid HTML, the ability to render with dynamic font sizes, and the need to know sizes for positioning, this can't be done without JS. The main conflict is, if the size of the font is dynamic, you can't get that information with CSS alone, and if you can't get that information, you can't determine positioning information.

Comment: I guess I will have to go down the JS route - anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxz5g9rq/1/)

```
.filter-category {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 20px; //set the list height, so the child can be place on top of it
}
.filter-list {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -60px; // hide it just below the parent so the animation is short & nice
   background: white;
   width: 200px; // i change it to prevent overflow-x on the body
   margin: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.filter-category:hover {
   overflow: visible;
}
.filter-category:hover ul.filter-list {
   bottom: 20px;
   -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
   -moz-transition: 5s ease;
   -o-transition: .5s ease;
   transition: .5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but am unable to set list height, this needs to be dynamic.